# Combine noises with correct blending

Tags: texturing

I'm a substance designer user and pretty new to Blender. What I'm trying to do is combining two noises so that the output is coherent.

From my experiments, say you have a Musgrave and a Noise node, mixing them through the MixRGB node doesn't do the job because it basically blends the colors, not the actual noise information.

Can you give me some pointers if and how I could achieve this? Also, I'd like to be able to restrict the second node area to a specific area, so that basically it affects only a small part of the first node.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm no substance designer user so I actually don't understand what you mean... what do you mean with the noise information? The information is given through the colors or grey values, so mixing the colors mixes the information as well. Or do you want it to be mixed in a different way? The MixRGB node has multiple mixing methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would mix it like this (the *Vector Math* node will combine the "noise information" instead of just mixing the colors):

[image: Warp1]

This is the mask texture used for the mix to restrict the "warp" area:

[image: Warp2]

Try changing the brightness (white/black) of the second mix color (grey) to see it's effect. In the example below I "animate" the warp by changing the scale of the musgrave texture. There are other ways of doing it including using a mapping node with a *#frame* value written in a Value Node connected to the location input of the mapping node (I will add an image later - I am currently short on time ;)

[image: Loop]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Alessandro Mastronardi, in that case, mark his answer as correct (the check mark on the top left of his answer)  ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can for example mix the *Texture Coordinate* with the second texture (here, a *Musgrave*) into a *Color > MixRGB*, and increase the factor of the *MixRGB* if you want more effect from the second texture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. Your hint should put me in the right direction indeed. One more question... is it possible to restrict coordinates so that the blend occurs only on a smaller area. To clarify, so that the underlying texture gets overlayed only on a small and specific area?

Comment: I guess so but I don't know how to do it easily, someone will probably tell

Comment: To make the blend only occur in a specific area, you must use a third texture (b&W - could be from another noise texture), and use that as a mask (_Fac_ input).